# how to declare ng-show and ng-hide in one div

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In my project I had a requirement to use both `ng-show` and `ng-hide` in one `div`.
I felt that's a bad practice.

**html code:**

```
<div ng-hide="itemDIv2" ng-show="itemDIv2"> 
   <input type="text" placeholder="Item Name" ng-model="itemname"> 
   <div> 
       <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Save" ng-click="subcatiems()>
   </div>
</div>
```

**another div:**

```
<div><button  class='btn' ng-click="catitems2()">Add items to Category</button></div>
```

**controller:**

```
$scope.catitems2 = function(){
     return $scope.itemDIv2 = true; 
}
```

how to take a condition that initially it is on hide and when the button is clicked i want to make `ng-show="itemDIv2"` to `true` so that I can show the `div` one more tome.

Comment: bas practice is to write lo-o-ong lines of code.

Comment: Why not use ng-if?

Comment: Why you are want this? ngShow/ngHide just reversed version of each other.

Comment: Initialize the $scope.itemDIv2 to false, and remove ng-hide would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on on @vp_arth's comment, you don't need both. But you're on the right track with the boolean flag.

I would suggest making these changes:

Add this object to the controller scope:

```
$scope.ui = { showDiv: false };
```

And in the template, change the button to:

```
button ng-click="ui.showDiv = !ui.showDiv" /
```

And instead of both ng-show and ng-hide, use:

```
ng-show="ui.showDiv"
```

This way you don't need a catitems2() function, and the div or what you want to show starts off hidden.

Here's a working JSFiddle of the changes:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/6534/

Answer (score 5):

You don't need both `ng-show` and `ng-hide` on same div to acheive this functionality. You can toggle the scope variable `$scope.itemDIv2` on button click.

```
<div class="settings-heading " style="background-color: #f2f2f2;"  
  ng-show="itemDIv2" ng-init='itemDIv2=true'> 
  Demo text
</div>  

 <div>
   <button  class='btn' ng-click="itemDIv2 = !itemDIv2" >
     Add items to Category
   </button>
 </div>
```

Working JSBin: https://jsbin.com/vaduwan/2/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 1):

Both `ngShow` and `ngHide` just add/remove `NG_HIDE_CLASS` class to element.

Try read the sources to understand that: [ngShowHide](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngShowHide.js#L162-L178)

Use one boolean scope variable and set it to neccesary value with one of that directives.